# Enable Parallel publishing in Sitecore

Tags: publishing, processor

Is it possible in Sitecore to publish items simultaneously for two users? If a user is publishing and at the same time the second user starts publishing then publishing should not go to queue for 2nd user.

I have tried changing `<setting name="Publishing.MaxDegreeOfParallelism" value="2" />` in `sitecore.config` .But it doesn't work. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: can you check this https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15940/avoid-publishing-queues-allow-concurrent-users-to-publish-on-sitecore-8-1

Comment: It didn't help with queue problem